# I need to send this variable in php

Tags: php, json, web-services

I need to create a function which receives a variable and sends it as json. My expected json output is :

```
{   "item": [
    {
        "a": "string",
        "b": "string",
        "c": 0
    }],
    "country": 0
}
```

This is my function in php:

```
$postData['item'] = 
array(
    'a' => "12345",
    'b' => "98765",
    'c' =>  0000,
);
$postData['country']= 1;
```

And this generates:

```
<pre>
array(2) {
    ['item'] => array(1) {
        ['sn'] => string(13) '9597/08639650'
    }
    ['country'] => int(717808)
}
</pre>
```

I'm also getting an error which states: 
`["item is not of a type(s) array"]`

What am I doing wrong here?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

I cannot replicate your issue without more information. Here is a [working repl.it](https://repl.it/OGsI) with your code. It displays the expected result with no issues:

```
<pre>array(2) {
     ["item"]=>
        array(3) {
          ["a"]=>
          string(5) "12345"
          ["b"]=>
          string(5) "98765"
          ["c"]=>
          int(0)
        }
     ["country"]=>
       int(1)
}
</pre>
```

And `json_encode($postData)` :

```
string(52) "{"item":{"a":"12345","b":"98765","c":0},"country":1}"
```

If you cannot get this working, please post more information about what is happening between the instantiation of `$postData` and when you are printing it.